# symfony2 update related entity in eventListener

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, event-listener

We have three entities:

1. MaterialAssigned
2. Stock
3. Job

`MaterialAssigned` holds three fields:

1. Quantity (int)
2. Relation with a `Job` Entity
3. Relation with a `Stock` entity

We are try to write a `preUpdate()` on MaterialAssigned which takes old and new `Quantity` values, do some calculation and update the overall total quantity in the related `Stock` Entity.
When we `var_dump()` values along our logic, everything seems to work as expected, however the related `Stock` entity never gets updated.

That's the relevant code from the EventListener:

```
public function preUpdate(PreUpdateEventArgs $eventArgs)
{
    $entity = $eventArgs->getEntity();
     if ($entity instanceof MaterialAssigned) {

        $changeArray = $eventArgs->getEntityChangeSet();
        $pre_quantity = $changeArray['quantity'][0];
        $post_quantity = $changeArray['quantity'][1];

        // Here we call the function to do the calculation, for testing we just use a fixed value
        $entity->getStock()->setTotal(9999);

        $em   = $eventArgs->getEntityManager();
        $uow  = $em->getUnitOfWork();
        $meta = $em->getClassMetadata(get_class($entity));
        $uow->recomputeSingleEntityChangeSet($meta, $entity);
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried recomputing the changes to the `Stock` entity too? Or "instead" as you're not actually doing anything to the `MaterialAssigned` entity directly.

Comment: @Qoop Do you mean define `$stock = $entity->getStock()`, then do the `setTotal()` and at the and calling `$meta = $em->getClassMetadata(get_class($stock)); $uow->recomputeSingleEntityChangeSet($meta, $stock);` ? If so, we tried already and again there is no error and no update still

Comment: Yeah that was what I meant.

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is that `preUpdate` is restricted by Doctrine to not allow any Entities to be updated from within this method. `onFlush` on the other hand does allow the update of Entities, and replaces the need for three separate methods (update, persist, remove).

We then found the following guide which hints at a solution: [Tobias Sjösten's guide](http://vvv.tobiassjosten.net/symfony/update-associated-entities-in-doctrine/)

Our code now looks like:

```
public function onFlush(OnFlushEventArgs $args)
{
    $this->em = $args->getEntityManager();
    $uow = $this->em->getUnitOfWork();

    // These collects an array of all the changes that are going to be flushed.
    // If you do not wish to see deleted entities just remove the line $uow->getScheduledEntityDeletions()
    $entities = array_merge(
        $uow->getScheduledEntityInsertions(),
        $uow->getScheduledEntityUpdates(),
        $uow->getScheduledEntityDeletions()
    );

    foreach ($entities as $entity) {

        if ($entity instanceof MaterialAssigned) {

            // This gets an array filled with the changes for the entire entity
            $changeArray = $uow->getEntityChangeSet($entity);

            $stock = $entity->getStock();

            // Here we call our function passing $changeArray.
            // This does some math and update the value. For simplicity we just
            // set the value manually in this example
            $stock->setTotal(9999);

            $md = $this->em->getClassMetadata('Northerncam\AppBundle\Entity\Stock');
            $uow->recomputeSingleEntityChangeSet($md, $stock);
        }
    }
}
```

This is the `print_r()` of `$changeArray`:

```
array (size=1)
    'quantity' =>
        array (size=2)
            0 => int 10
            1 => int 50
```