# Which Doctrine Lifecycle Event for update?

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I have a Listener class which when Post or Thread Entity is created, updates these fields in Category table:

`last_post_thread_title`

`last_post_thread_slug`

`last_poster_username`

`last_post_body`

`last_post_created_at`

`is_last_post_op`

and `last_post_created_at` in Thread table.

```
class LastPostListener
{
    public function postPersist(LifeCycleEventArgs $args) 
    {
        $entity = $args->getObject();
        $entityManager = $args->getObjectManager();

        $this->handleEvent($entityManager, $entity);
    }

    public function postUpdate(LifeCycleEventArgs $args) 
    {
        $entity = $args->getObject();
        $entityManager = $args->getObjectManager();

        $this->handleEvent($entityManager, $entity);
    }

    public function handleEvent($entityManager, $entity)
    {
        if (!$entity instanceof Post && !$entity instanceof Thread) {
            return;
    }

        $isPost = $entity instanceof Post;

        $thread = $isPost ? $entity->getThread() : $entity;

        $post = $isPost ? $entity : $thread;

        $category = $thread->getCategory();
        $category->setLastPostThreadTitle($thread->getTitle());
        $category->setLastPostThreadSlug($thread->getSlug());
        $category->setLastPostBody($post->getBody());
        $category->setLastPosterUsername($post->getUser()->getUsername());
        $category->setLastPostCreatedAt($post->getCreatedAt());
        $category->setIsLastPostOp(!$isPost);

        $thread->setLastPostCreatedAt($entity->getCreatedAt());

        $entityManager->persist($thread, $category);
        $entityManager->flush();
    }
}
```

However when EXISTING Thread or Post Entity is edited, before mentioned Category table fields are not updated.

It's the same with prePersist() and preUpdate() Events, with or without flushing.

Of course, it's possible to add all of the `$category->set` lines directly to Controller `update` function, but it's dirty.

Which Event should be used here or maybe there is some another solution? Thanks

Comment: It would be good if you will update your question with explanations of what do you mean by "doesn't work". What do you trying to implement with this code?

Comment: Since postUpdate event is called inside flush method, and entity changes are not revelvant, you must use another way for update data. See https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/events.html#postupdate-postremove-postpersist This may be a good aproach https://stackoverflow.com/a/25312851/3497902.

Answer (score 2):

Reason for such behavior is explained into [Doctrine documentation](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/events.html#implementing-event-listeners) with details of allowed operations within each of event types. If you will take a look at this article - you will see that [`preUpdate`](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/events.html#preupdate) event is very restrictive and [`postUpdate`](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/events.html#postupdate-postremove-postpersist) is not even relevant. Generally speaking main reason of your current problem is an attempt to call `flush()` while `flush()` is already running.

If you want to sync information - there is several ways:

1. You can use [`onFlush`](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/events.html#onflush) event listener. This event gives you access to all computed changes that are scheduled for commit and it will allow you to examine these changes to decide what to update. However it may be not that easy because you will need to deal with `UnitOfWork` methods that exposes internal representations of computed changes e.g. [`getScheduledEntityUpdates()`](https://github.com/doctrine/orm/blob/434820973cadf2da2d66e7184be370084cc32ca8/lib/Doctrine/ORM/UnitOfWork.php#L3241) and other similar methods. Also it will be required to manually recompute change sets in a case if you will made some changes in entities within this event.
2. You can implement separate class that will provide own `flush()` method that will need to look basically like this:

   ```
   class CustomFlush {
       /**
        * @var EntityManager
        */
       private $em;
       /**
        * @var array
        */
       private $changes = [];

       public function flush($entity = null) {
           // Perform normal flushing operation
           $this->em->flush($entity);
           // If there was some changes collected - apply them
           if (!empty($this->changes)) {
               $categories = [];
               // Apply changes from $this->changes to Category entities,
               // collect them in $categories and flush separately
               if (!empty($categories)) {
                   $this->em->flush($categories);
               }
           }
       }

       public function preUpdate(LifeCycleEventArgs $args) {
           // Collect updates from Post and Thread and store it into $this->changes
       }
   }
   ```